# Customize ERPNext Kanban

Tags: python, erp, kanban, erpnext, frappe

I'm studying the possibility for my team to move on ERPNext. I'm trying some functionalities to see what could ERPNext take care of.

One of these is the Kanban. ERPNext provides a built-in Kanban that can be customized. I was indeed able to create my own columns but I have several issues:

- First of all, there are more columns than the basic ones. Which break the front end (we can't scroll right). I suppose it can be fixed easily. [unscrollable kanban](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYYBv.png)
- Second, my tasks do not appear on the Kanban because I created new columns, and task's status options are linked to the column name I suppose, but I can't find a way to add more options. If I try to customize on the task form, I get an error `You can’t set ‘Options’ for field Status ERPNext`. If I try to do it on task DocType, the field is grey and I can't modify it.
  I found this [github issue](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/pull/16157), If I understand correctly they want you to create a new set of options but it's not really customization ?
- Finally, The kanban display your tasks by status. But would it be possible to have also the kanban displaying sections for each projects ? It is possible with RedMine, and really convenient for us since we have several projects with tasks that we want to see on a single page.

I feel like ERPNext really is powerful and customizable but it's quite hard to understand how they want us to really work.
Thanks and happy new year !